# IntelliJ keymaps for teams

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

I vaguely remember there being an option in IntelliJ a few years ago, where you could specify a "centralized" keymap repository, which would allow all team members using IntelliJ to use the same exact keymapping.  This is perfect, for example, if you're pair-programming.

However, I've recently looked for references to it, and I can't find anything like that in the latest version of IntelliJ.  Did this actually exist, or is there an alternate way of doing this inside IntelliJ?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to the Settings Repository plugin that allows you to sync any settings you store in a Git repository across different instances of the IDE. More info and instructions can be found at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html